# Python: Fixing a string With cp1252 characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, encoding

**Shorter version:** 
How can I write a function that will take a string that contains string-representations of characters (eg "This is a character \u200a") and replace them with the characters they represent (eg "This is a character     ")

**Longer Version**
I need to write a function that will take the following string:

```
<p>"â€Š\'These things matter\' a lotâ€”in Virginia, Florida, North Carolina, and Ohioâ€”just to name a few states."</p>
```

and turn it into

```
<p>" 'These things matter' a lot—in Virginia, Florida, North Carolina, and Ohio—just to name a few states."</p>
```

The best I've come up with so far is to encode it as cp1252 and then decode it as utf-8

```
>>> x.encode("cp1252").decode("utf-8")
<p>"\u200a\'These things matter\' a lot—in Virginia, Florida, North Carolina, and Ohio—just to name a few states."</p>
```

Is there a function I could write or a library that would get me the last step of the way in terms of unescaping the \' characters and finding that awful "hairspace" encoded character?

Thanks!

Comment: [`Unidecode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) can convert non-ASCII characters to their closest ASCII equivalent, if that's what you're looking for. If that's *not* what you're looking for you need to be more specific about the result you need. If you `print` that string instead of just inspecting it you'll probably find that those characters can be printed.

Comment: where did you get this string ? form web page ? It could have information about encoding and maybe you should use this inforamtion to correctly convert text.

Comment: @MarkRansom that was indeed the case: my terminal was outputting the characters like that, but the content was proper. 

Thank you for pointing that out!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your text is correct but use `print()` to see it.

```
>>> x = "â€Š\'These things matter\' a lotâ€”in Virginia, Florida, North Carolina, and Ohioâ€”just to name a few states."

>>> print(x.encode("cp1252").decode("utf-8"))


 'These things matter' a lot—in Virginia, Florida, North Carolina, and Ohio—just to name a few states.
```

`Python Shell` normally use `print(repr(...))` to automatically display results of every line of code. It gives more usefull information (when you test code) than normal `print(...)`

```
>>> print(repr(x.encode("cp1252").decode("utf-8")))

"\u200a\'These things matter\' a lot—in Virginia, Florida, North Carolina, and Ohio—just to name a few states."
```